# Performance on View in MySQL

Tags: mysql, performance, view

I have created a view on a table like so:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW V_BLA AS
SELECT
    CONVERT(UIT_DNR USING latin1) AS internNr,
    UIT_SNR AS schuldnr,
    TRIM((SELECT SCH_OMS FROM BUSCHU WHERE SCH_DNR = UIT_DNR AND SCH_VNR = UIT_SNR)) AS omschrijving,
    CASE
        WHEN (SELECT TABDATA FROM BDTABE WHERE TABNR = 9000 AND VOLGNR = 1 AND TABTAAL = 0) = 1 THEN -- ALGEMEEN BESTAND
            (SELECT CONCAT(TRIM(SC_FNAAM), ' ', TRIM(SC_VNAAM)) FROM SDSCIN WHERE SC_NR = LEFT(UIT_SCHULDEISER, 4))
        ELSE
            (SELECT CONCAT(TRIM(SC_FNAAM), ' ', TRIM(SC_VNAAM)) FROM BUSCIN WHERE SC_NR = 100000 - UIT_SCHULDEISER)
    END AS schuldeiser,
    UIT_DATUM AS datum,
    UIT_VLGNR AS volgnummer,
    UIT_BEDRAG AS bedrag,
    CONVERT(IF(
        UIT_COBE_DAT = 0,
        NULL,
        CONCAT(
            RIGHT(UIT_COBE_DAT, 4), '-', 
            IF(UIT_COBE_DAT < 10000000,
                CONCAT(MID(UIT_COBE_DAT, 2, 2), '-0', LEFT(UIT_COBE_DAT, 1)),
                CONCAT(MID(UIT_COBE_DAT, 3, 2), '-', LEFT(UIT_COBE_DAT, 2))
            ))), DATE) AS datumBetaallijst,
    TRIM(UIT_MEDEDELING) AS mededeling
FROM BUUITG;
```

The problem is that the performance is really bad. It takes up to 10 seconds to generate output when I try to select some rows by internNr. I have created the necessary indices:

- BDTABE: CREATE INDEX BDTABE_TABNR_VOLGNR ON BDTABE(TABNR, VOLGNR);
- SDSCIN: CREATE INDEX SDSCIN_SC_NR ON SDSCIN(SC_NR);
- BUSCIN: CREATE INDEX BUSCIN_SC_NR ON BUSCIN(SC_NR);

An extra index on UIT_DNR on BUUITG doesn't improve anything.

My explain plan when I do a select:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM V_BLA WHERE interNr = 'something';

+---+--------------------+------------+-----+------------------------+------------------------+----+-----------------------------------------------------------+--------+--------+-----------------------------------------------------+
| 1 |      PRIMARY       | <derived2> | ref |      <auto_key0>       |      <auto_key0>       | 22 |                           const                           |   10   | 100.00 |                     Using where                     |
+---+--------------------+------------+-----+------------------------+------------------------+----+-----------------------------------------------------------+--------+--------+-----------------------------------------------------+
| 2 | DERIVED            | BUUITG     | ALL |                        |                        |    |                                                           | 208498 | 100.00 |                                                     |
| 6 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | BUSCIN     | ref | BUSCIN_SC_NR           | BUSCIN_SC_NR           |  4 | func                                                      |      1 | 100.00 | Using index condition                               |
| 5 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY |            |     |                        |                        |    |                                                           |        |        | Impossible WHERE noticed after reading const tables |
| 4 | SUBQUERY           | BDTABE     | ref | BDTABE_TABNR_VOLGNR    | BDTABE_TABNR_VOLGNR    | 14 | const,const                                               |      1 | 100.00 | Using where                                         |
| 3 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | BUSCHU     | ref | BUSCHU_SCH_VNR_SCH_DNR | BUSCHU_SCH_VNR_SCH_DNR | 12 | export_winsoc.BUUITG.UIT_SNR,export_winsoc.BUUITG.UIT_DNR |      1 | 100.00 |                                                     |
+---+--------------------+------------+-----+------------------------+------------------------+----+-----------------------------------------------------------+--------+--------+-----------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Have you tried moving the subqueries from the select list to derived tables / simple joins in the `from` clause?

Comment: I can't change the table structure...

Comment: I did not ask you to change your table structure...

Comment: I see now what you asked. Your suggestion wasn't described well enough for me.

Comment: Perhaps you should familiarise yourself with the concept of derived tables. They are quite fundamental to writing more complex queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already indicated in the comment, I would move the subqueries in the select list to the `from` clause, either as simple joins, or derived tables. I use left joins, but feel free to change them to inner joins based on your requirements and data. Pls also review the join conditions as well, since I had to guess in certain cases which fields are in which tables.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW V_BLA AS
SELECT
    CONVERT(UIT_DNR USING latin1) AS internNr,
    UIT_SNR AS schuldnr,
    TRIM(BUSCHU.SCH_OMS ) AS omschrijving,
    CASE
        WHEN BDTABE.TABDATA  = 1 THEN -- ALGEMEEN BESTAND
            CONCAT(TRIM(SDSCIN.SC_FNAAM), ' ', TRIM(SDSCIN.SC_VNAAM)) 
        ELSE
            CONCAT(TRIM(BUSCIN.SC_FNAAM), ' ', TRIM(BUSCIN.SC_VNAAM) 
    END AS schuldeiser,
    UIT_DATUM AS datum,
    UIT_VLGNR AS volgnummer,
    UIT_BEDRAG AS bedrag,
    CONVERT(IF(
        UIT_COBE_DAT = 0,
        NULL,
        CONCAT(
            RIGHT(UIT_COBE_DAT, 4), '-', 
            IF(UIT_COBE_DAT < 10000000,
                CONCAT(MID(UIT_COBE_DAT, 2, 2), '-0', LEFT(UIT_COBE_DAT, 1)),
                CONCAT(MID(UIT_COBE_DAT, 3, 2), '-', LEFT(UIT_COBE_DAT, 2))
            ))), DATE) AS datumBetaallijst,
    TRIM(UIT_MEDEDELING) AS mededeling
FROM BUUITG
LEFT JOIN BUSCHU ON BUSCHU.SCH_DNR=BUUITG.UIT_DNR AND BUSCHU.SCH_VNR=BUUITG.UIT_VNR
LEFT JOIN BDTABE ON BDTABE.TABNR = 9000 AND BDTABE.VOLGNR = 1 AND BDTABE.TABTAAL = 0 --did not find any common fields between the 2 tables
LEFT JOIN SDSCIN ON SDSCIN.SC_NR = LEFT(BUUITGUIT_SCHULDEISER, 4)
LEFT JOIN BUSCIN ON BUSCIN.SC_NR = 100000 - BUUITG.UIT_SCHULDEISER
```

Comment: So, I have tried your approach, and it makes things only worse :(. The performance drops with about 15%.

Comment: Do you have the appropriate indexes to support the joins, such as SCH_DNR and SCH_VNR fields? Have you checked using the explain if they are indeed used?

Comment: Yes, the correct indexes are there. It uses all correct indexes, except it does a full table scan on BUUITG itself.

Comment: 1. In you question there is no index mentioned on SCH_DNR and SCH_VNR fields... 2. That's hardly surprising, since BUUITG is on the left hand side of the join expressions and there are no filters applied to it.

Comment: In fact I have 8 views which I created. I created the indexes on SCH_DNR and SCH_VNR earlier when creating one of the other views. It's funny, this is the least complex query view and it gives me moest problems...

Comment: Is it possible that if I run the SELECT statement which describes the view, the performance is OK? Or should the execution time always be roughly the same as I would have when I would select from the view?

Comment: If you do a `select * from viewname`, then the 2 performances should be the same. However, if you apply further filters on the view, then the 2 will not be the same.

Comment: I will always have a select * and where internNr = 'bla'. Sometimes, there might be some additional filters on the fields (i.e.: AND bedrag = 15).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I have concluded that the usage of a view is the villain in this story. When just using the query itself, I reduced it to 69 milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

```
CONVERT(UIT_DNR USING latin1) AS internNr
```

Prevents the use of an index on `UIT_DNR`, which seems vital to the query for which you provided the explain.  (Nevermind the typo: internr vs internnr.)

That are your connection parameters?   What is `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'char%`'?  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table.

See if changing that one line to

```
UIT_DNR AS internNr
```

and adding

```
INDEX(UIT_DNR, UIT_BEDRAG)
```

will help.