# MySQL - Select from view or direct select

Tags: mysql, sql, view

I have created a view on a simple table. My problem is that my average execution time of a select on that view is about 29 seconds.
However, if I run the select statement which describes the view directly, the query executes in about 0.015 seconds.

Now, I have looked up some info, and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10302615/mysql-views-performance) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789332/is-a-mysql-view-faster-than-a-normal-query), people basically say that it should be roughly the same since a view is just a stored query.

Is it possible that I have this much of a difference in time? I have tried using SQL_NO_CACHE to make sure no cache is used so I get representative data when testing both options.

I would prefer to keep my view unless I have no option in reducing costs.

Comment: Running the select that describes the view is not the same as selecting from it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3492926/sql-query-takes-more-time-when-run-in-a-view

Comment: @DanBracuk, could you be more specific in terms of the execution time? I know it's not the same obviously. But how does it affect execution time? Is it possible that I have such an enormous difference in time?

Comment: Thanks for your help, guys, the answer is: yes, it is possible to have this much difference in time!

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of research and trial and error I have concluded that on even simple queries and views, the performance can be a huge difference when selecting * from a view or just running the select query that is described in the creation of the view.

Comment: Where did your research lead in terms of documentation, blogs, or other answers?

Comment: @Drew, other questions on SE through some Google searches. And of course a lot of trial and error :).

Comment: Ok, can you share some stat at least. Just trying to make this a question we don't delete or find useless.

Comment: @Drew, I've mentioned my sources in the question itself. Also, I asked a question here previously (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38433003/performance-on-view-in-mysql/38441841#38441841). One of the answers state that if I query my view with a where clause, my execution time can differ from executing the raw select statement which the view is described by.